# gtk text entry receiving buffer from socket?

Tags: text, gtk, buffer, gtkentry

I made a simple window, using C and glade, with only a gtk textview and a gtk text entry, and at this moment my textview receives buffer/data from  UDP socket, and it prints perfectly with the following command:

```
gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter (buffer, & iter); 
gtk_text_buffer_insert (buffer, & iter, getbuf, -1);
```

And now I want a similar command to make my text entry to get the buffer/data that I receive from the socket. I've found this `gtk_entry_buffer_insert_text` which may be the right one, but I think that I'm missing something else, and I guess that I've to use the `guint`, but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: Oh and just to let you know, the "getbuf" is my variable which contains the data that i've received from socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, actually i solved the problem using only:

```
gtk_entry_set_text (GTK_ENTRY(message_entry), getbuf);
```

I only had to put my message_entry in global to work :D